# React doesn't render without Reloading the page on URL Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to create a dashboard structure, with redirect on button click to different components.

I am able to do the URL change, but still the page doesn't load without a hard reload on that url.

My code as Below : 
**Navigate.JS**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import SalesDashBoard from "./salesDashBoard";
import OrderScreen from "./OrderScreen";


function SDNavigator(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/salesDesk" component={SalesDashBoard}/>
                    <Route exact path="/salesDesk/OrderScreen" component={OrderScreen}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )}
export default SDNavigator;
```

**SalesDashBoard.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

function SalesDashBoard() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <h3>Dashboard Links</h3>
                    <Button
                        component={Link} to="/salesDesk/OrderScreen"
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                    >
                        Login
                    </Button>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default SalesDashBoard;
```

**OrderScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function OrderScreen() {
    return (
        <div Order Screen />
    );
}
export default OrderScreen;
```

The page is loading when reload after the click is done and URL is changed, without reloading its still showing the Dashboard page.

PS : I have already routing this from App.js -> DashBoard.js, Thats working fine.

Comment: You shouldn't have a `<Router />` wrapping every one of your components. It should only be at the top level of your component tree. That's your issue; the link in `SalesDashBoard.js` is associated with the router closest in the virtual DOM tree, and that router literally has no routes.

Comment: Thanks @101arrowz, Now i found the logical issue and the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
function SalesDashBoard() {
    return (
      // Remove Router
            <div>
                <h3>Dashboard Links</h3>
                    <Button
                        component={Link} to="/salesDesk/OrderScreen"
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                    >
                        Login
                    </Button>
            </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: glad to help :)